# How to get indices using Jenssegers Mongodb

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, indexing

I'm needing to get the indexes of a collection in mongodb using laravel, I know that in mongo compass you can use the $ indexStats which returns the indexes, try to replicate the same as follows

```
DB::connection('mongodb')->collection("audience")->timeout(-1)->raw(function($collection){
    return $collection->aggregate([
        [
           '$indexStats' => new \stdClass()
        ]
    ], ["allowDiskUse" => true]);
});
```

But with a dd () check the result and it was the following

```
MongoDB\Driver\Cursor {#2009}
```

The truth is that I would not know what that is, if someone knows what I am doing wrong or how to obtain the indexes it would help me a lot

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution, it was simply that MongoDB\Driver\Cursor{# 2009} has to be converted into an array, then I detail how the code is

```
$query = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection("audience")->raw(function($collection){
        return $collection->aggregate([
            [
                '$indexStats' => new \stdClass()
            ]
        ], ["allowDiskUse" => true]);
    });
dd($query->toArray());
```

And in case you need to convert it to a laravel collection I do it in the following way

```
dd(collect(json_decode(\MongoDB\BSON\toJSON(\MongoDB\BSON\fromPHP($query->toArray())), true)));
```

I convert it to a json, decode it and finally use the collect function.

I hope it helps someone. **Greetings :D**